# What is the accepted file extension to use for pipe delimited files?

Tags: file-extension, csv

I am parsing a file of data whose fields are separated by pipes. The records are separated by newlines. This is similar to a CSV file or even a TSV file (http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/TSV.html), but I wonder what the accepted file extension for pipe delimited data is?

I do not see one specifically mentioned in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delimiter-separated_values and I have not found mention of one in the 5 or so StackOverflow questions I referenced.

The WP article suggests to me that, by way of "extension" from comma to CSV and tab to TSV, the extension should be PSV. Not everyone calls a pipe a pipe though.

Maybe there is a popular software package that uses pipe delimited data and has an extension for it, thereby setting the de facto standard?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had this same question because I wanted to follow the standard *if there was any*. The obvious choice here is `.psv` considering the naming system of `.csv` and `.tsv` - however, I couldn't find this in use anywhere.

The most common extension that I could find associated with a pipe-delimited file is simply `.txt`. Exports from census.gov and most other government entities use `.txt` for pipe-delimited files.

Comment: I added an extra tag of "hl7" to this post because the HL7 data interchange format typically uses bars | and carats ^ to delimit data. Its extension tends to be "hl7". I'll use csv or txt for pipe delimited data. psv could be confusing to someone- "hey what do I open that with? photoshop vector?" but any program that reads csv can probably intelligently change the delimiter to a pipe. Thanks, leek.